# Getting "Run TIme Error 13: Type Mismatch" while parsing a JSON using JSONConverter

Tags: json, excel, vba

Microsoft Office 365 - Excel Macros

JSON:

```
{
   "expand":"schema,names",
   "startAt":0,
   "maxResults":1000,
   "total":8,
   "issues":[
      {
         "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
         "id":"10011",
         "self":"http://192.168.99.100:8080/rest/api/2/issue/10011",
         "key":"TES-12",
         "fields":{
            "issuetype":{

            },
            "components":[

            ],
            "timespent":null,
            "customfield_10101":[
               "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@1d4aa0ee[id=2,rapidViewId=1,state=FUTURE,name=Facebook March 2020 Release,startDate=2020-05-30T20:22:00.000Z,endDate=2020-06-18T20:22:00.000Z,completeDate=,activatedDate=,sequence=2,goal=]"
            ],
            "customfield_10102":"TES-1"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Code written to extract "customfield_10101" and store the values in String variable

```
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
Dim tempName As Variant
tempName = Json("issues")(1)("fields")("customfield_10101")(1)
```

Getting in last line of the code

> Run Time Error 13

Comment: Is this the exact code or an extract of the actual code? Where are you getting the `responseText` from? there needs to be an HTTP request object somewhere. If this request actually exists in your code then you need to refer to it explicitly like: `requestName.responseText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of your code that does the parsing is correct.
The problem seems to be that you're not passing the json correctly to the `JsonConverter.ParseJson()`.

I am not sure whether you are getting this JSON as a response to some HTTP request that you're sending to a webpage or you just have it stored somewhere and you're just trying to parse it.

If in fact you're getting the json as a response to an HTTP request, then you need to refer to this request explicitly. So, for the sake of demonstration, I will assume there is an HTTP request object named `req` somewhere in your code. In that case your code should look like so:

```
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(req.responseText)
```

If you're using a `With-End With` block to send the request, as it's usually the case, then your code would look like this:

```
With req
    '.open ...
    ' ...code related to the request...
    '.send...

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
```

If there are no requests in your code and you just have the json stored somewhere as a string and you need to parse it then all you have to do is pass that string to `JsonConverter.ParseJson()`.

So for example, if the json string is stored in `cell A1` of `Sheet1` all you need is this:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Json As Object
Dim tempName As Variant
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sht.Range("A1").Value)
tempName = Json("issues")(1)("fields")("customfield_10101")(1)
```